# reading from a serial port - Question marks appearing instead of values

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm currently converting an old vbs application to a c# application so I can provide more functionality.  The purpose of this application is to scan an identity card and take the id from it.  I can then use this to import the data into a door access system via a CSV file.

Now here is my problem.  When I use the vb application to scan a card via the COM port it has a value of:

3E8783D0

I can see this works correctly.  However when I come to use my new program in c# and scan the barcode I get the following output:

2??E878????

So I can see that the card is scanning.  But part of the code is filled in with question marks.

I have looked into altering the baud rate etc and this is the closest I can come to meaningful data.  The settings for the COM port are the same as the old VB program so I wouldn't have thought this shouldn't be a problem?

The coding I have used is shown below.  Can someone help to explain why the question marks are appearing?  Have I missed something obvious?  The form I am using is laid out with a text button and a start / stop button to prepare the device for input from the proximity sensor.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM1";
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 4800;
        serialPort1.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
        serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
        serialPort1.RtsEnable = false;
        serialPort1.ReadTimeout = 500;
        serialPort1.WriteTimeout = 500;
        serialPort1.Open();
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            buttonStart.Enabled = false;
            buttonStop.Enabled = true;
            textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
        }
    }

    private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            buttonStart.Enabled = true;
            buttonStop.Enabled = false;
            textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen) serialPort1.Close();
    }

    private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText("!");
        textBox1.AppendText(RxString);
    }

    private string ExtractPACID(string s)
    {
        return s.ToString() + "";
    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
    }
```

Comment: You're not configuring the data bits or stop bits.  You're also setting DTR but you haven't configured handshaking - does your device need hardware handshaking?  Can you show the full configuration from the VB program?  What device are you connecting to?

Comment: The original VB program settings are:  Port=COM1 Baud=4800 Parity=N dataBits=7 stopBits=1.  I have tried adding the dataBits and Stopbits to my code however when I do this I get the return data "I7WN7a6Gl" when scanning the id card so I thought I would remove this as I the solution above only has the question marks and looked closer to the results I needed.  I am connecting to a "PAC Smart Card Reader 40192".The original code doesn't have handshaking so I have left this out.  Sorry to sound daft as you can tell this isn't my most knowledgeable subject and any help is greatly received

Comment: Definitely you need to set data and stop bits correctly.  I've had problems with the .NET `SerialPort` class in the past, mind you - always at low baud rates.  Specifically I remember having trouble with one device that operated at 1200 baud and it consistently failed to communicate properly.  I never bothered trying to debug it, but it was definitely something wrong with the `SerialPort` class (HyperTerminal and several other applications could read the device fine).  I ended up writing the COM code into a DLL in another language in that case.

Comment: 3E8783D0 can also be 4 byte values, displayed in hex notation.  In which case using ReadExisting() is wrong and *will* generate question marks since values like 87 and D0 are not ASCII codes.  Using Read() is then required.

Comment: Either you have 8 data bits and no parity (8-N-1 default) or 7 data bits and either even (more common) or odd parity (7-E-1).  7 databits and no parity is not used really.

Comment: @KevinCook Agreed that it is odd to see 7-N-1, but if we assume that OP is not lying then that is the configuration that is required and working in VB6.

Comment: Not exactly.  Ignoring parity and framing errors in VB6 was way too easy.  Not implementing the ErrorReceived event in .NET is too.

Comment: Thanks for your comments I will look at fixing this in my code soon and give you some feedback.  The original VB coding was done by someone else and I have literally copied the settings from their code.  I am not really an expert on Serial Port Comms that why I'm at the point I am.  All comments have been gratefully received. :-)

Comment: @HansPassant But would it work?  I've never used VB6, but I've not known parity and framing configurations to work anywhere else when they are mismatched with the device.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your input.  The problem is now solved.  I needed to read the hex data.  Using - BaudRate: 4800 ; Databits: 7; Parity: None; Stop bits: 1;  This displays the correct value after converting it to a Byte.

Comment: @PhilC Mr Challinor, please write up this solution in an answer and mark it as accepted to allow other community members to make use of this post.